# In Bash scripting, are commands following an '&&' operator considered child processes of the preceding command?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to make sense of the scoping precedence of environment variables in Bash.  I've come to understand that when you use a script to modify environment variables, those modifications are only available to child processes.  That each script creates its own environment scope it can modify and that scope is passed off to child processes, but doesn't effect the scope of the parent process. (Side question: Is that correct?)

The modifications can be pulled into a parent process's using `source` on the file that makes the modifications (which causes the commands being executed in the script to instead be executed in the parent context).

My question is, does the `&&` operator create a child scope?

For instance, if I have a script, `modify-environment.sh`, that `exports` some environment variables like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MY_VAR=hi
```

And another script, `do-something.sh`, that attempts to use them:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $MY_VAR
```

And I call them like this:

```
$ ./modify-environment.sh && ./do-something.sh
```

Will `do-something.sh` inherit the modified environment variables from `modify-environment.sh`?

**Edit**

I updated to rephrase the question, because I realized the answer is "No" and what I was previously seeing had to do with the fact that the script I was looking at was called using `eval` and was printing `export MY_VAR=value`, so the `export` was being called in the parent context, which is why it was getting passed to the `&&` operator.

Comment: @DavisHerring Example added.  Does that clarify what I was asking?  I'm pretty sure I've figured out the answer, and it's "No."

Comment: Everything stated in the, er, question is correct.

Comment: Your question sounded a bit confused.  It looks like you figured it out yourself.  For the SO Q&A format it's better to take that last paragraph out of the actual question text and post it as an answer.  You *are* definitely allowed to answer your own questions!

Comment: I'd avoid thinking of environment inheritance in terms of scope -- that's not quite what's going on. For one thing, shell variables can have scope (global vs. local to a function), which is orthogonal to the subprocess (/subshell) hierarchy. Also, when a subprocess is forked, it inherits a *copy* of the parent process's environment, but subsequent changes (in either process) don't affect the other process (in either direction). This is different from how shared-scope variables work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>using the  command does not execute the script that changes the environmental variable,</s> `source` imports all functions and variables defined in that script, it also executes all commands in the particular context where the script was sourced. if and only if you explicitly execute the script , the parent process won't have access to the variables ( environmental and non environmental) declared in that script. Executing a script creates a new process but sourcing a script does not fork a new process

i think you mistaking `&&` for `&`, `&&` is a logical operator ( this applies to all programming languages ) but `&` places a command / script as a background job therefore the parent process won't have access to any variable or function placed in the background

for example

sourcing

```
# myenv.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

export NAME="${HOSTNAME}"
```

at the command line

```
source myenv.sh
echo "${NAME}" # 73mp74710n
```

executing

```
# execute.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export NAME="${hostname}"
```

at the command line

```
chmod +x execute.sh
./execute.sh
echo "${NAME}"
```

at the command line

```
export NAME="${HOSTNAME}" &
echo ${NAME} # nothing shows up    
export NAME="${HOSTNAME}" && echo "${NAME}" # 73mp74710n
```

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command))

**EDIT:** fix a wrong assumption of how source works base on the below comments

Comment: `source`/`.` *does* execute the commands in the sourced script.

Comment: `source` and `.` execute scripts in the sense that they run all of the commands in the scripts (it *doed not* just import functions and variables). For example, if a script contains commands to move, copy, or delete files, `source`ing that script will move, copy, or delete the files just like it would if the script were run normally. The only sense in which it doesn't execute the script is that it doesn't use the `exec()`-family system calls on the script (which would run it under a new shell).

Answer (score 1):

The parent process is the shell  not the first command. in this case. (first process is ended).